# Can't delete posts and can't add a post without an image

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am learning CakePHP by trying to create a note application. However, I have two annoying bugs which have stopped me from going further and being able to complete my app.

**EDIT:** you can see a demo at: http://jeeremie.com (**u:** *username* / **p:** *demo123* - you can also create a new account if you want).

I added an option to upload a picture to my notes. The uploader works just fine however if I don't upload a picture, CakePHP tells me the post has been added successfully though I don't see my new note, neither on the site or database. The code for the `ADD` view is:

```
<!-- File: /app/views/notes/add.ctp --> 
<h2>Add Note</h2>
<hr />
<?php
echo $form->create('Note',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $form->input('title', array( 'label' => 'Enter Title:' ));
echo $form->input('body', array( 'label' => 'Enter your note:' ), array('rows' => '10'));
echo $form->input('file',array('type' => 'file'), array( 'label' => 'Attach a file:' ));
echo $form->input('id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo '<hr />';
echo $form->end('Save Note');
?>
```

Second, I can't delete any post though, again, it tells me is has been deleted successfully but the post still remains. Below the code for the controller:

```
<!-- File: /app/controllers/notes_controller.php -->

<?php
class NotesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Notes';
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

    var $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 3,
        'order' => array('Note.modified' => 'desc')
    );

    function index() {
        $condition = array('user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'));
        $this->set('notes', $this->paginate('Note', $condition));
        $this->helpers['Paginator'] = array('ajax' => 'Ajax');
        //$this->set('notes', $this->Note->find('all'));
        //$this->Note->recursive = 0;
    }

    function note($id = null) {
        $this->Note->id = $id;        
        $this->set('note', $this->Note->read());   
    }

    function add() {
        $this->layout = 'page';
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data['Note']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if ($this->Note->save($this->data['Note']) == true) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The note has been saved', 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Oops! The note could not be saved. Please, try again.', 'flash_error');
            }
        }
    }

    function delete($id) {
        $this->Note->delete($id);
        $this->Session->setFlash('The note with id: '.$id.' has been deleted.', 'flash_success');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }


    function edit($id = null) {
        $this->Note->id = $id;
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->Note->read();
        } else {
            if ($this->Note->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your note has been updated.', 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }


}
?>
```

And last, the notes view:

```
<!-- File: /app/views/notes/index.ctp -->
<?php echo $html->link('Add Post',array('controller' => 'notes', 'action' => 'add'), array('class' => 'add'))?>
<ul id="myNotes">   
<?php foreach ($notes as $note): ?> 

    <li>
        <div class="thb">
            <?php 
            //Build the img url
            $base_url = $this->base;
            $imgUrl = $base_url . '/app/webroot/media/' . $note['Note']['dirname'] . '/' . $note['Note']['basename'];
            //display the thumb
            if(!empty ($note['Note']['file'])) {
                echo '<img class="thb" src="' . $imgUrl . '" alt="' . $note['Note']['title'] .'" />'; 
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $html->link($text->truncate($note['Note']['title'], 40), array('controller' => 'notes', 'action' => 'note', $note['Note']['id'])); ?>
        <span><?php echo $time->relativeTime($note['Note']['modified']); ?></span></h2> 
        <?php /* Edit/Delete Button */ echo $html->link('Edit', array('action'=>'edit', $note['Note']['id'])) . ' | ' . $html->link('Delete', array('action' => 'delete', $note['Note']['id']), null, 'Are you sure?' ); ?>

        <p>
        <?php 
            $note = $note['Note']['body'];
            $noteUrls = $text->autoLink($note);
            echo  $text->truncate($note, 120);
        ?>
        </p>

    </li> 
<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
<!-- Shows the page numbers -->
<?php echo $paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
<?php echo $paginator->numbers(); ?>
<?php echo $paginator->counter(); ?>
<?php echo $paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
```

Does anyone know what the problem  is  here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your not saving right.
You Add function set the flash message if:

```
$this->Note->save($this->data['Note']) == true
```

I don't understand why your trying to save that way...

Why not save all the information the user input in the form like this:

```
if($this->Note->save($this->data)){
if success code goes here...
}
```

This will take all the information that was input and save it. 
Also, you seem to be missing this:

```
$this->Note->create();
```

Did you bake your application or did you just code it all yourself?

Comment: Thanks a lot of the help. As I said, I am learning. I coded all myself. Using the console on Windows is not great. I could switch to Linux but then I can't use the Adobe products. Besides, I am not sure to fully understand how this bake thing works at the moment so I prefer to skip it at the moment.

Anyway, the code you gave me fixed the issue with the delete button but not when I save the post without a file. Where goes "$this->Note->create();"? Inside the IF statement?

Comment: Actually, I still can't delete my notes. It worked just for 2-3 comments, not for all of them. I will try to put the files on the server so you can try it by yourself. Hold on. It is going to take a while.

Comment: Ok, I have moved the files to the server: http://jeeremie.com (u: username / p: demo123 - you can also create a new account if you want).

Comment: testing it out now... by the way, the CakePHP console on windows is very easy to use, I also develop in a windows environment for the same reason you stated, and console works perfect and does 90 percent of the work for you...

Comment: yes, I have to read more about it. It sounds interesting. Basically, when use ($ cake bake), it is going to generate the code for you  (add, view, edit, delete...), right?

Answer (score 0):

First off, here is a link that shows you how to add cakePHP (the cake shell command) to you windows path, this will let you use it from anywhere.
First place a fresh cakePHP installation somewhere so that you can always have this in a set place.
Than go here and set cake in windows path:
[Setting Windows path](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)

Aside from that, this is what the Basic add method is supposed to look like:

```
function add() {
if (!empty($this->data)) {
   $this->Article->create();
   if ($this->Article->save($this->data)) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article has been saved ', true));
   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
}
```

This is what the basic delete method looks like:

```
function admin_delete($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for article', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    if ($this->Article->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Article deleted', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Article was not deleted', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

So my recommendation: 
1. learn to use cake from the shell - it will change you life!

1. try out what I listed above.

Comment: Thanks. I already set up the cakephp console on Windows, got some errors though but I will fix that later. I am doing everything manually at the moment so I can learn CakePHP and PHP a bit more. I am a UI designer, not a back end developer :) Anyway, the code above did not change anything. Thanks for the help